# EF Code First one to one relationship without navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relationship, one-to-one

Suppose I have:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne<Blog>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
     public int BlogId { get; set; }
     public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

And it easily works for one to many:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne<Blog>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId);
```

Is there a way to do the same for **one to one**, something like this or may be there is another approach for solving this issue:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne<Blog>()
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId);
```

Would be very thankful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, just do it like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne<Blog>()
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Post>(p => p.BlogId);
```